# Oracle Apex Dynamic Heading depending on sql

Tags: oracle, report, oracle-apex, heading

Since several weeks I try to find a way to have dynamic headings in my interactive report in APEX (dynamic in means of an sql statement).

A short example of what i want to achieve:

```
|      KPI_NAME       | yesterdays values|
|---------------------|------------------|
|  Selled Sausages    |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|  ...                |         ...      |
```

But instead of "yesterdays values" i want to have the Date inserted, which is e.g. the max date from a table.

Is there any workaround, that would allow me to do that?
For conditional formatting (which is also not a built-in function there are plenty workarounds, but i couldn't adapt them to column headings manipulation)

Comment: Hi have a look here https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=9093:4:1285326052700::NO:::
on page 4 you will find interactive report and in which look for empno which is the first column check the header name if you want something like this which can be achieved using PAGE_ITEM create computation on it get whatever value want from table point BEFORE REGION and go to Interactive report-> Column -> heading -> empno &MY_PAGE_ITEM. (dont forgot the last DOT) refresh page you will see the changed heading

Comment: Hi Pranav Shah, that is exactly what i have been looking for. Didn't know that it is possible to refer to Page Items in the Heading Field.  Thank you very much!!!